# Failed <<< osrf_testing_tools_cpp while compiling ROS from source

Tags: ros

I was compiling ROS2 from source on Ubuntu. I received this error,

```
Failed   <<< osrf_testing_tools_cpp
```

when running the command,

```
colcon build --symlink-install
```

this is the full error
[image]

Is there any reason why I would be getting this error?